# Why does HTML/CSS add space after large p tag?

Tags: html, css

I want a header for my page, which will say 'WebsiteName.com', in huge letters, then about 20px below it, I need a `<hr>` tag. However for some reason, there's a pretty big amount of space added below it?

[image: Here's my example]

How would I remove the space below it?

```css
.global_header p {
  font-size: 70px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="global_header">
  <b><p>WebsiteName.com</p></b>
  <hr>
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `margin-bottom: 0px;`

```
.global_header p {
    font-size: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will set the top and bottom margin of a `<p>` to `1em` (along with other elements so be careful).

An `em` is equal to the current font size. If the font size is `16px` then `1em = 16px, 2em = 32px, etc.`. `em`s allow you to size things relatively. This is why you end up with such large margins on your `<p>`, the font size is `70px` so your top/bottom margin are also `70px` each.

If you wanted to enlarge or reduce the size of text **and** wanted padding, margin etc. to match (relatively) then an `em` is a nice choice. There's [also `rem`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#rem).

One way to combat this is to not use a relative unit for all paragraphs and adjust accordingly when needed later. In your use case this would be specifying a specific amount of margin.

```css
p {
  margin: 16px 0;
}
.global_header p {
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  /* Set margin as needed. 
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="global_header">
  <b><p>WebsiteName.com</p></b>
  <hr>
</div>
<br>
```